# From under what blocks can daylight sensors detect sunlight?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm looking for a good block to cover up my daylight sensor that would look nice with my build design. I had read the [Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_Sensor) on it and tested a few blocks that I thought would have worked, some did (glass and carpets), and some didn't (slabs, stairs, and pistons). Also, how was SethBling able to do this (you'll see it at around 1:00), the Daylight Sensor has a solid block (red wool) above it:

Could someone please come up with a list of blocks that daylight sensors can be placed under, and still detect sunlight? Please note if they decrease the light level as well.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The wiki doesn't give a clear answer, and it mentions something about transparent blocks, and a link to them. However I tried some of those, and they didn't work, So I'm a bit confused. Also, I could test every block in creative mode, but I watched a SethBling video recently that made me question how they work. I'll make an edit linking to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The daylight sensor can theoretically generate a signal while underneath any sort of block.

This is because it generates a signal that is proportional to the amount of sunlight it is exposed to (on any side, including underneath). Sunlight will penetrate any block the game deems 'transparent' (e.g. slabs, stairs, pistons, etc.) and will also 'wrap around' underneath solid blocks that have a direct path to the sky nearby. Sunlight that wraps in this way diminishes in strength by 1 level for each block away from an unobstructed view of the sky.

There is also currently a bug that will cause daylight sensors that are completely covered by solid blocks to emit a signal at night time.

Comment: Wasn't the light-through-stairs bug fixed?

Comment: I used the bug you mentioned in the last paragraph and it worked day-light-fully! (Terrible pun, I know...) Thanks so much!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, as well as light-through-slabs.